# Is there Any way to convert a table to this?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Original Table:

[image]

To This:

[image]

I tried using Pivot table but Pivot indicates the sum and I cant seem to fix the rows to make them unique values

Comment: Are you seriously converting apples and bananas into Manila and Tokyo??? :-) :-) :-)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your input and expected output got nothing in common but the dates.  Please, specify how fruits evolve to cities

Answer (score 0):

As I think, you want to rotate table so, that columnes becomes rows and rows become columnes.

have you tried: Copy -> Paste Special -> Transpose